# Will paginate on ordered list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using will_paginate in my rails app: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

In my posts controller:

```
@posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

In my view:

```
<ol>
<%= render (@posts) %>
</ol>

<%= will_paginate @posts :next_label => "next" , :previous_label => 'previous' %>
```

In my post partial:

```
<li><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></li>
```

On the first page this gives me a list order list 1-10, but when I go to the next page, I get a different list of 1-10. How do I get it so that on the next page it's 11-20 ?

---

```
Started GET "/?page=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-30 22:11:06 -0400
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2"}
```

Comment: Can you try like `Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).order("created_at DESC")` ?

Comment: Just tried that, does the same thing

Comment: Can you post the log for page 2 request?It will give better indication of what's going on.

Comment: I suspect something wrong with the url, it should be `/posts?&page=2`, might need to check your routes again

Comment: It has nothing to do with the urls, I specifically have the posts routes that way

Comment: How do I get the ordered list to adjust based on the page??

Comment: @Katie H ol tag is having a fresh render, it will every time order from 1 to 10 on each page.

Comment: I just can't believe will_paginate is so hard to use, you @KatieH must be doing something wrong, cause I have used will_paginate in a few apps and never had to write all that bunch of code you have in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the following in your view:--

```
<%- page = params[:page].to_i%>
<ol start = "#{page > 1 ? (((page -1) * 10) + 1) : 1}">
<%= render (@posts) %>
</ol>

<%= will_paginate @posts :next_label => "next" , :previous_label => 'previous' %>
```

You should specify the staring number for ol tag.

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis see my comment on question itself and time.

Comment: Sure, just did. Revoking.

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis You do not have to revoke, I do not think that way about copyright or patent. Knowledge can not be confined, and it can not be claimed over. You and every body else are free to post either same or similar answers. We came here with nothing, won't take anything with us too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

Comment: Hi @Katie H, That's not exactly the same with the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar in my app once, and then I thought, why ordering by `created_at` if I could order by `ID` that is much better.. I mean you can't have in db that `post` with id 1 `created_at` date to be later than post with id 10, post with id 1 will be first in both cases if you order by date or id. Also ordering by ID is handled much better, cause `created_at` saves time stamps with seconds that might get confusing at ordering. So I would do:

```
@posts = Post.order("id DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

**!note:** You don't touch(update/modify) `created_at` field in your app, `created_at` should remain unchanged, if you need to show when post was published you better add a `published_at` field.